# I lost my passport which had my u.s stamp on it, will my new one have it ? I have a copy of my old passport #, does that help?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports

I entered the states for a visit. (I'm Canadian) Ended up getting married so we started filing for permanent U.S. resident. (husband's an American citizen) While filing, I lost my passport, which had my u.s stamp on it for border passage! However, I do have a copy of my lost passport, which also had passport # on it! I'm wondering when I get a new passport, will I be able to get the U.S. stamp on it again? Without crossing border back & forth? Please help!! Any info is appreciated! Already called Canadian embassy to report my lost passport.

Answer (score 2):

You are not going to get a stamp on your new passport, because you didn't use that passport to enter. The stamp is just a one-time record; you cannot replace it.

Usually, the thing that matters for a foreigner to be able to stay in the U.S. is the I-94, which documents their status and duration of stay. For people entering since mid-2013 by air or sea, the I-94 is electronic, and so the loss of a passport would not affect the ability to look up and print out the I-94 anyway. For people entering by land, they may still get a paper I-94, and if the paper I-94 is lost, then it is necessary to apply for a replacement I-94.

However, as a Canadian citizen visitor, you are generally not issued an I-94, even before 2013. You can head to the [I-94 website](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/) to see if you have one; if you do, then that's all you need. If not, then I guess your copy of the entry stamp can serve to show that you entered legally.

Comment: Canadian non-immigrants properly admitted nearly always have an I-94 record now no matter how they arrived and even if they don't get the piece of paper (I was only once admitted without an I-94 when on a 2 hour errand across the Niagara River; he wanted to close the I-94 left open from a similar errand the month before and not leave a new one open). Finding the record might be a problem if the entry wasn't with (something tied to) a passport or if one no longer knows the passport number. I often didn't get entry stamps, though.